# initiating an object to other object

Tags: java

This is code to merge two sorted linked list. Now my question lies in merge function given. Why we are referencing new_node1 to new_node. Whats wrong in using new_node1 directly in the function instead of doing
       "Node new_node=new_node1;"
(Anyways I tried using directly but it is not generating the required output. It just generates the last item of the merged list) Does new_node object uses default constructor? Elaborate explanation will be really helpful.Thanks in advance.

```
 static class Node{
    int data;
    Node next;
    Node(int num){
        data=num;
        next=null;
    }
}

// Function for merging two sorted linked list

public void merge(Linkedlist list1,Linkedlist list2){       
    Linkedlist l=new Linkedlist();

    Node new_node1=new Node(0); 
    Node new_node=new_node1;   //This  line of code is my doubt!
    while(list1.head!=null || list2.head!=null){    
        if(list1.head!=null && list2.head!=null){
        if(list1.head.data<=list2.head.data ){
            new_node.next=list1.head; // what difference it makes by using new_node.next instead of new_node1
            list1.head=list1.head.next;         

        }
        else{
            new_node.next=list2.head;
            list2.head=list2.head.next; 
            }           
        }
        else if(list1.head==null){           
                new_node.next=list2.head;
                list2.head=list2.head.next; 
            }
        else if(list2.head==null){          
                new_node.next=list1.head;
                list1.head=list1.head.next;                 
        }
        new_node=new_node.next;
        //new_node1=new_node1.next;
    }
    l.printlist(new_node1);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only difference is in the last line, `l.printlist(new_node1);`. If you use `new_node1` all the way through the loop, then you'll be printing the last node. When you use `new_node` all the way through the loop, then `new_node1` remains unchanged, pointing to the head of the list.

I suggest renaming `new_node1` to `head_node` and `new_node` to `current_node`. That will make it easier to understand. Then you get something like this:

```
Node head_node = new Node(0); 
Node current_node = head_node;

// .. build the entire list of nodes ..

l.printlist(head_node);
```

Comment: And can you please tell what constructor the current_node will be using ? Is it the default constructor or the constructor that is defined me?

Comment: There is no new object constructed. No constructor is called. Both variables point to the same object, which is constructed only once, on the line `Node head_node = new Node(0);`. `current_node` just points to the same object that `head_node` points to.

Answer (score -1):

Here

```
new_node1
```

is an object.

While

```
new_node
```

is a reference variable which is used to point to the nodes in the list

Comment: You might be thinking of C rather than Java.

Comment: In case it's not clear: neither `new_node1` nor `new_node` are objects, per se. They are both references to objects. Initially, they are references to the same object; at the end of each iteration through the loop, `new_node` becomes a reference to a new object, while `new_node1` remains the original reference.